# Variable length argument list error

Tags: c, variadic-functions

many years ago I wrote a custom print function declared like this:

```
void my_printf(char *format_string, ... )
{
    // too complex to list here
}
```

and I could call it like this:

```
my_printf("Number of apples = %d\n",apple);
```

This function has always worked perfectly. I now wish to make a wrapper function that takes an extra integer at the start like this:

`void my_printf_extra(int extra,char *format_string, ...` )

that could be called like this:

```
my_printf_extra(debug_level,"Number of apples = %d\n",apple);
```

and I would like the wrapper function to call the original in a way something like this:

```
void my_printf_extra(int extra,char *format_string, ... )
{
    if (extra == some_test)
    {
        my_printf(** not quite sure what goes here **);
    }
}
```

My guess was this:

```
void my_printf_extra(int extra,char *format_string, ... )
{
    va_list vptr;

    if (extra == some_test)
    {
        va_start(vptr,format_string);
        my_printf(format_string,vptr);
        va_end(vptr);
    }
}
```

but it's not working. In my final output I see

```
Number of apples = -46467968
```

or some such garbage number (when the true value was 1). I see similar garbage when calling my_printf_extra with a string. I suspect that my processing of va_list is wrong, but I can not fathom how exactly.

**EDIT:** my_printf() is super flexible and can print to all sorts of different places. Sometimes it just appends the text to a rich-edit-control-window. It all depends on assorted flags as well as the contents of what's being printed.

Comment: Passing the `va_list` to another function does not fill in the arguments as if they had been passed. A reasonable solution here might be to make the existing `my_printf` a simpler routine that initializes a `va_list` and passes it to `my_printf_core`, which does the rest of the work. Then your `my_printf_extra` could call `my_printf_core` instead of `my_printf`. (`my_printf_core` could be equivalent to the `vfprintf` mentioned in the marked original, so essentially the same solution unless you need customizations in `my_printf_core`.)

Comment: @Jean-Francois Fabre: I don't see how the duplicate helps. The code is identical to my buggy original.

Comment: you misread. 1) it's not identical because it's using `vfprintf` and 2) it works. So there isn't a real solution in the general case, but with `printf` family functions you can work it out using `vfprintf`

Comment: I'm not printing to stdout. The my_printf function is actually rather complex and can print to a variety of different locations or a file or graphically - in assorted colours etc - sometimes more than one location. Dependant on flags

Comment: are you printing to a file? a buffer?

Comment: See edits to previous comment

Comment: I have now worked out my error but can not put the answer here because the question has been marked as duplicate.

Comment: I've reopened, you can answer your own question, I hope it's not a duplicate in disguise. Let's see the answer, ping me when you're done.

Comment: OT: I'd expect `const `in `my_printf(const char *format_string, ... )`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `my_printf` doesn't expect a `va_list`, you can't pass one to it.

This is a case where using a macro makes sense:

```
#define my_printf_extra(extra, format_string, ... ) \
do {\
    if ((extra) == some_test)\
    {\
        my_printf((format_string), __VA_ARGS__);\
    }\
} while (0)
```

The `__VA_ARGS__` macro replaces all of the extra parameters.  Note that this requires a compiler that supports C99.

Alternately, you can modify my_printf to add the extra logic, change the name to something internal, then define `my_printf` and `my_printf_extra` as macros that call the internal function:

```
void my_printf_impl(int extra, char *format_string, ... )
{
    if (extra != some_test) {
        return;
    }

    ...
}

#define EXTRA_DEFAULT 0
#define my_printf(format_string, ...) \
    my_printf_impl(EXTRA_DEFAULT, format_string, __VA_ARGS__)
#define my_printf_extra(extra, format_string, ...) \
    my_printf_impl(extra, format_string, __VA_ARGS__)
```

Comment: is that compatible with c89?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I don't believe so.  `__VA_ARGS__` was introduced with C99.